# I'm missing 746.52 GB of space on my hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

I have a new 3TB Seagate Barracuda hard drive and it will not let me use this unallocated space:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you did not partition the drives with GPT, but with MBR instead.  MBR only allows drives up to 2.19 TiB.  (3TB − 2.19 is about 750 GiB).

This means you can not create **a single** 3TB volume.

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing it, its just unallocated.   Right click on the space, and click format, select the file system type...

You can also expand the size of the other partitions by the unallocated space.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on each of the unallocated partitions and select the format option to create partitions